# finding the highest hour in a list

Tags: python, list, python-class

```
class volunteerList:
    def __init__ (self, groupName):
        self.__vList = []
        self.__groupName = groupName

    def setGroupName (self, newGroupName):
        self.__groupName = newGroupName

    def getGroupName (self):
        return self.__groupName

    def getvList (self):
        return self.__vList

    def addVolunteer (self, volunteer):
        self.getvList().append(volunteer)


    def highestHour (self):
        details = ""
        highestHourList = []
        highest = self.__vList[0].getHourContribution()
        for volunteer in self.__vList:
            hour = volunteer.getHourContribution()
            if hour == highest:
                highestHourList.append(hour)
            elif hour > highest:
                highestHourList = [hour]
                highest = hour
                #highestHourList.append(hour)
        if volunteer.getType().lower() == "f":
            details = details + "{} - {} years old - flood volunteer".format(volunteer.getName(), volunteer.getAge()) + "\n"
        elif volunteer.getType().lower() == "p":
            details = details + "{} - {} years old - pandemic volunteer".format(volunteer.getName(), volunteer.getAge()) + "\n"
        elif volunteer.getType().lower() == "e":
            details = details + "{} - {} years old - earthquake volunteer".format(volunteer.getName(), volunteer.getAge()) + "\n"
        elif volunteer.getType().lower() == "t":
            details = details + "{} - {} years old - tsunami volunteer".format(volunteer.getName(), volunteer.getAge()) + "\n"

        return details
```

```
def main ():
    groupName = input("Enter your group name: ")
    newGroup = volunteerList(groupName)
    print ("\n")

    choice = menu()

    while choice != "0":
        if choice == "1":
            name = input("Name of volunteer? ")
            age = int(input("Age? "))
            volunteerType = input("Type of volunteer ('F/P/E/T'): ")
            volunteerType = volunteerType.lower()
            while volunteerType not in "fpet":
                print ("Invalid type! Please enter again!")
                volunteerType = input("Type of volunteer ('F/P/E/T'): ")
                volunteerType = volunteerType.lower()

            hourCont = int(input("Contribution hour? "))
            while hourCont <= 0:
                print ("Invalid value! Please enter again!")
                hourCont = int(input("Contribution hour? "))

            newGroup.addVolunteer(volunteer(name, age, volunteerType, hourCont))
            print ("... Volunteer has been added successfully.")
            print ("\n")
            choice = menu()

        elif choice == "6":
            print ("Volunteer with highest contribution hour:")
            print (newGroup.highestHour())
            print ("\n)
```

I'm not sure the code on highestHour() correct or wrong. I was planning to find the highest hour of the volunteer(s). If there are more than 1 highest hour of volunteer (same hour), display everything. My output was only one highest hour of volunteer or display 2 same line of statement instead of the example before.

Wondering how to display all volunteer that are highest hour?
The display sample will be:
a - 36 years old - pandemic volunteer
b - 25 years old - flood volunteer

Comment: Can you add the code, where you create those classes and call their methods? Also, I'm guessing `def getHourContribution (self):` belongs to the volunteer class, so is there an indent missing?

Comment: Add a [mcve]. Don't make us guess what to input, just hard-code some values and instantiate your class and reproduce the error

Comment: Sorry for didn't write it properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Here you go:

```py
class volunteer:
    def __init__ (self, name, age, type, hourContribution):
        self.__name = name
        self.__age = age
        self.__type = type
        self.__hourContribution = hourContribution

    def getHourContribution (self):
        return self.__hourContribution

class volunteerList:
    def __init__ (self, groupName):
        self.vList = []
        self.__groupName = groupName

    def highestHour (self):
        highHourList = []
        hourList = []
        for volunteer in self.vList:
            hourList.append(volunteer.getHourContribution())
        highest = max(hourList)
        for hour in hourList:
            if hour == highest:
                highHourList.append(hour)
        print(highHourList)

new = volunteerList("one")
vol1 = volunteer("", 1, "", 5)
vol2 = volunteer("", 1, "", 10)
vol3 = volunteer("", 1, "", 10)
vol4 = volunteer("", 1, "", 10)
vol5 = volunteer("", 1, "", 1)
new.vList = [vol1, vol2, vol3, vol4, vol5]
new.highestHour()
```

#### Alternative highestHour function

```py
def highestHour (self):
    highHourList = []
    largest = self.vList[0].getHourContribution()
    for volunteer in self.vList:
        hour = volunteer.getHourContribution()
        if hour == largest:
            highHourList.append(hour)
        elif hour > largest:
            highHourList = [hour]
            largest = hour
    print(highHourList)
```

Needs some cleaning up, but you get the idea.

Comment: If I wan my output as:
a aged 2 is a tsunami volunteer which has contributed 6 hour(s).
b aged 2 is a tsunami volunteer which has contributed 6 hour(s).

Instead of:
b aged 2 is a tsunami volunteer which has contributed 6 hour(s).
b aged 2 is a tsunami volunteer which has contributed 6 hour(s).

Comment: If you have more questions, please update your code and make a new post with that updated code (even if it is not working yet). In this post, your question regarded "finding the highest hour in a list", which I have solved already. Please mark this post as answered if your original question has been solved.